# <select> ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, html-select

I am using jQuery on my site and i have a update section on my project and I have three dropdowns:

- Completed?
- Hours Worked
- Who worked on this project?

I am trying to create an ajax call using jQuery to when I select it, call a $.ajax() and send the data to my php page to update my mysql database.

I am guessing I could do this:

Get the data in the select and store in a variable, and send it as data using $.ajax, but I am not sure how I would CAPTURE the value after you select and then run the ajax?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As FryGuy said the $.post method is probably your best bet although I'd lay it out like this:

```
$("#project select").change(function(){ // use one selector for all 3 selects
    $.post("someurl.php",{
        // data to send
        completed: $("select#completed").val(),
        hours:     $("select#hours").val(),
        who:       $("select#who").val()
    }, function(data) {
        // do callback stuff with the server response 'data' here
    });
});
```

This might not be exactly what you wanted if the three selects occur more than once on the page. I'd recommend reading through the jquery docs to get a handle on events. As for pulling out data you just need to use selectors and methods like `.text()`, `.val()`, `.html()`, `.attr()` etc... at the point you need them. The information you want is always in the DOM somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for this! So will this update EACH select regardless of which one I update correct? I would rather this instead of three different ones.

And I would catch the data using: $_POST['completed'], etc, etc.

Comment: Yep, so whichever select you change it will fire the post and each time it will take the current value of each select.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [jQuery post method](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post).. something like:

```
$.post("updater.php", { completed: variableWithCompletedFromSelect } );
```

Just call that in the on change event on the select, and pass in the select's value. Then your php script will have $_POST['completed'] with the new value.